# Event Mysql não executa no horário determinado

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados

Criei um evento no mysql para que **todos os dias** no horário **00:05:00** iniciando no dia 18/07/2021, ele execute um update em uma tabela, só que ele não está executando no horário determinado, o que pode estar acontecendo? Segue o script que utilizei para criação do Event

OBS.: Ele até fez a primeira execução (no dia que criei o evento), mas não repetiu nos demais dias, mesmo configurado como um evento recorrente.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` EVENT `EventStatusUpdate`
    ON SCHEDULE
        EVERY 24 HOUR STARTS '2021-07-18 00:05:00'
    ON COMPLETION PRESERVE
    ENABLE
    COMMENT ''
    DO BEGIN

UPDATE usuario
SET   status = 1
WHERE status = 0;

END
```

Comment: Mysql não é meu forte, mas sugiro que dê uma olhada a fundo na documentação [CREATE EVENT Statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-event.html) principalmente em relação ao `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`

Comment: Obrigado por responder @gleisin-dev, já havia verificado isso e também o timezone estão corretos.

Answer (score -1):

*"iniciando no dia 18/07/2021"* esse deve ser o problema, se tentar criar um evento com uma data retroativa ele não vai funcionar, o `STARTS` deve sempre ser uma data posterior.

Por exemplo, no momento dessa resposta é "20/07/20121 15:00", portanto só pode agendar (no caso do seu exemplo) para iniciar a partir de "21/07/20121 00:05:00".

Crie o evento com o `STARTS` para o dia a seguir e vai funcionar.
Pode também mudar o `EVERY 24 HOUR STARTS` para `EVERY 1 DAY STARTS`

Por fim, não esqueça de a seguir confirmar se o evento foi criado corretamente e também **se o scheduler está ativo**, senão ele não vai iniciar o evento na próxima vez.  Para confirmar use o comando `SHOW PROCESSLIST`, veja se na lista aparece seu evento e o "event_scheduler", que é o agente que inicia os eventos agendados.

Comment: Obrigado por responder Ricardo, na verdade quando eu agendei para o dia 18/07/2021 para iniciar 00:05, eu criei antes disso, criei no dia 17 umas 23 hrs e fiquei aguardando pra ver se ele iria executar mesmo, daí executou... achei que tava tudo certo, mas aí nos demais dias ele não fez mais.

Já havia testado também com o EVERY 1 DAY e também não funcionou, já tenho 2 dias procurando uma solução na internet... também já dei um SHOW EVENTS e ele está criado e habilitado, também olhei a variável event_scheduler se estava ativa, me perdoe faltou passar também essas informações

Comment: Vi agora o SHOW PROCESSLIST, apareceu isso aqui:

Id User  Host db Command Time State Info
"5" "event_scheduler" "localhost" \N "Daemon" "36560" "Waiting for next activation" \N
"8" "root" "localhost:52082" "db_sistema" "Query" "0" "starting" "SHOW PROCESSLIST"
"9" "root" "localhost:52083" \N "Sleep" "5" "" \N

Não entendo muito desse comando, teria que aparecer aí uma linha com o nome do evento que criei?

Comment: Observei aqui que ontem o evento executou no horário certo (00:05) e hoje já não executou novamente, que loucura...